# Alignment check in WebAssembly when emulating XMM intrinsics?

Tags: c, simd, webassembly, memory-alignment, emscripten

I'm trying to compile the PFFFT library (https://bitbucket.org/jpommier/) to WebAssembly using the `-msse` option to emulate the SSE intrinsics. Compilation works fine, but there's an alignment check that fails at runtime.

The alignment check macro that fails is:

`#  define VALIGNED(ptr) ((((long)(ptr)) & 0xF) == 0)`

I'm a bit lost here ... does anyone have a hint on how to perform the alignment check with WASM SIMD, or whether it's even necessary ?

Best,
n

Comment: The macro checks if the pointer `ptr` is aligned on a 16-byte boundary (i.e. the address should be a multiple of 16) - alignment is usually a hard requirement when using SIMD-instructions. Looking at https://github.com/WebAssembly/simd/blob/master/proposals/simd/SIMD.md#integer-to-integer-narrowing it seems it's also a requirement in WASM.

Comment: Just looked through the PFFFT code and if that macro fails, it looks like your input/output arguments (to the various functions) are not aligned correctly. Are you allocating the memory with correct alignment?

Comment: @MortenJensen: Alignment isn't a hard requirement for SIMD these days.  x86 SIMD has always has `movups` unaligned loads/stores, and these days they're fully efficient when the access is within a single cache line.  (And otherwise a minor penalty, extra latency and some throughput cost, which modern HW can hide pretty well.)  Without AVX, only `movups` / `movdqu` can do unaligned 16-byte load/store.  With AVX, memory operands don't require alignment by default, e.g. `vpaddb xmm0, xmm1, [rdi]` doesn't do alignment checking, only `vmovaps` does.

Comment: So with AVX, no cost in extra instructions to making a loop that will work for unaligned memory, letting hardware pay the cost for the occasional caller that passes a misaligned pointer.  (Instead of having software checking that runs every time, adding some overhead even for aligned inputs.)  I think on things like AArch64 SIMD, where there are no memory operands for ALU instructions, you can similarly always use unaligned loads/stores, hopefully with no penalty in the aligned case, but IDK.

Comment: Thanks for explaining @PeterCordes - so I guess the answer is that OP can omit the alignment check? Looks like it's only used two places in the code: https://bitbucket.org/jpommier/pffft/src/master/pffft.c lines 1622 + 1707

Comment: @MortenJensen: Yeah, if you can't ensure aligned allocation with WASM (IDK if that's possible), then you'll need to remove alignment checks.  (Or turn the assertions into code that does something special for the first unaligned vector, before entering a loop that starts at the start of the first aligned vector.  For some code, e.g. idempotent and/or copy-and-modify, that can be branchless, and aligned input means you don't overlap that first maybe-unaligned vector.)

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're writing C and compiling to WASM - it's not totally clear to me if you're also calling the PFFFT library from C.

Reading [the PFFFT-code](http://bitbucket.org/jpommier/pffft/src/master/pffft.c) at lines 1622 + 1707, only two places could fail the macro you're describing (`VALIGNED(ptr)`):

```
  1608  void pffft_transform_internal(PFFFT_Setup *setup, const float *finput, float *foutput, v4sf *scratch,
  1609                               pffft_direction_t direction, int ordered) {
   ...
  1622    assert(VALIGNED(finput) && VALIGNED(foutput));
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  1623  
   ...
```

and

```
  1677  void pffft_zconvolve_accumulate(PFFFT_Setup *s, const float *a, const float *b, float *ab, float scaling) {
   ...
  1707    assert(VALIGNED(a) && VALIGNED(b) && VALIGNED(ab));
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ...
```

So the "fault" can be placed at the caller(s) of `pffft_transform_internal(...)` and `pffft_zconvolve_accumulate(...)` :) The input pointers aren't correctly aligned.

If you are allocating the `float`-arrays yourself, are you using `aligned_alloc()` or emulating it yourself? (it's quick and easy! :))

According to @Peter Cordes you could also consider testing with the macros removed/disabled.

Comment: Yes, compiling from C to WASM, calling from JS. The "outermost" layer of memory (there's some internal work buffers) is allocated on the WASM heap from JS and passed to the WASM method. Not sure whether it's possible to allocate this with correct alignment. But, yes, I tried the scalar alignment check that PFFFT defines a few lines below, and that works. So I might also try removing it entirely. Thanks!